# Shared libraries (dlls) in memory) - how many copies?

Tags: .net, dll, .net-assembly

If I have two .Net applications that reference the same libraries in the GAC, and I have both applications launched concurrently and executing code that uses the shared library (or even one after the other), how many copies of the library will there be resident in memory?

The reason I ask is I am trying to improve the first-time execution speed of a process in an application, a large chunk of the first-time execution being taken up by loading a number of libraries from the GAC. I am considering pre-loading these by previously running a small application that references and uses the same libraries (perhaps when Windows starts up).

Will the 2nd application to run have access to the same copy of the now resident library, or will it still have to load its own copy? Instinct tells me that only one copy will need to be loaded into memory, but then things are not necessarily as you might expect them!

Comment: There's lots of literature on ".NET cold start performance", be sure to google it.  Doesn't have anything to do with memory, everything to do with disk speed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look, but my goal is to find a way (if possible) to preload assemblies so when the app in question executes, it doesn't have to (because user complain about the time taken).

Comment: Just tell them to start it more often.  So that [this feature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista_I/O_technologies#SuperFetch) takes care of it.  An SSD is the next solution.

Comment: Sadly an SSD is not a solution. We can't tell our customers to install SSDs on all their PCs just because our app is too slow (as they will perceive it).

Answer (score 1):

The GAC is  a "shared" location for assemblies so you don't have to keep multiple copies of them on disk, it's not shared memory. So in memory you'll have a copy of the dll for every process that uses it.

Sharing memory, as in two processes using the same instance of a dll is a completely different animal.

If you are looking at saving the time it takes to Jit your assemblies, as in your little app takes the hit, the GAC has nothing to do with it. It's the .net framework itself that deals with that, it caches compiled assemblies. So given your little app 'exercises' the assembly as in calls enough code to force JIT compilation, the next app will see a benefit, whether it's as big as you hope remains to be seen. It's a quick win, but..

So you are more likely to have a lasting and predictable impact, by asking yourself can I break up my code so all this stuff doesn't have to be loaded en masse, before I can do anything.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting the GAC is memory (I have 13 years' experience writing C# applications), and I am not looking to JIT them either. My point is once a library is loaded into memory, is it kept there and available to subsequently started application that use it, or do they load their own copy when needed?

Comment: @NeilHaughton From the point of view of the question you are asking, they load their own copy when needed.

Comment: To be absolutely clear - when two different applications using the same dll are both loaded and both have executed code in the dll, there are two copies of the dll in memory too? So running the first app doesn't save the second app from having to load the dll into memory as well?

Comment: Yep loaded up twice, otherwise they'd be sharing memory as in any objects and you'd have to deal with that all the time.

Comment: Thanks, that clears that up. Does that apply to system (ie .Net) libraries as well? Surely they are not loaded into memory once for every .Net application that is running, or are they?

Comment: Sharing a dll(not just .net) is no different to sharing an exe, you wouldn't load it, you would communicate with a process that had loaded it.

Comment: I think we are splitting hairs over the meaning of 'load'. I mean 'resident in memory'. Does every instance of a .Net application thatis currently running on a machine have its own in-memory copy of a given .Net assembly that is uses?  That was the question.